# Interval between two ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime, date

How to calculate the full difference between two `ZonedDateTime` instances with same `ZoneId`? In other words difference in all time unites.

Using Java 8 and don't what to use any third party library like `Joda` or something else.

```java
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.parse("2007-05-11T15:30:00Z");
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.parse("2008-03-01T13:00:00Z");

Duration.between(start, end); // PT7077H30M
Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), end.toLocalDate()) // P9M19D
```

Using `Joda-Time`

```java
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

DateTime start = DateTime.parse("2007-05-11T15:30:00Z");
DateTime end = DateTime.parse("2008-03-01T13:00:00Z");

Period period = new Period(start, end); // P9M2W4DT21H30M
```

How get a same result using standard Date/Time API?

Comment: `Duration.between(start, end)` ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-

Comment: I already made an answer and then you closed it, very sad.

Comment: I re-opened it for you. But I think, there will be no answer besides doing some coding with `Period` and `Duration`.

Comment: @Brad How get months and days from `Duration`? `Period` gives `9 months 19 days`.

Comment: I’m confused. Your code example is using *java.time*. But the you are talking about *Joda-Time*.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm asking how to achieve same result as in Joda, but using `java.time` .

Comment: Do you mean literally that string as output? Edit your Question to clarify. Also, this topic has been addressed multiple times already. Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: Tip: It rarely makes sense to mix years-months-days with hours-minutes-seconds (think about it). But if you insist on that, see the *ThreeTen-Extra* library with its `PeriodDuration` class.

Comment: @BasilBourque I didn't mean the string, but you can think as it. I've searched before posting and did not find anything suitable, all the are posting to calculate difference in a single `ChronoUnit`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196724/discussion-between-edgar-asatryan-and-basil-bourque).